# Nodejs and npm are not working because I mistakenly uninstalled/deleted some nodejs files

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, npm-package, nvm-windows

Recently, I was facing an error with my Git. So, I tried to uninstall/delete Git from my windows system so that I could reinstall it again from beginning. But, In that process I mistakenly deleted some files which were related to NodeJs and NPM.

Now, NodeJs and NPM are not working in my system. I have tried updating it. Uninstalled the NodeJs from the system and reinstalled it. But, Still I am facing the same error.

The error can be seen in the image....

[Here, you can see the 'node -v' command is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlIIf.png)

(The error is caused using npm only but not with node)

[Getting this exact same error with each and every npm command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MupmI.png)

Your Help will be appreciated.....!

WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE-

I tried to delete/uninstall the NodeJs from my system but I did not uninstall Each & Every file related to NodeJs from system because I thought It can cause some other new problems/issues with other softwares in my laptop.

Therefore, **I uninstalled the NodeJs normally** and then reinstalled it from the official website.

I was expecting that it would solve the issue but it didn't work.

I tried to resolve the issue using NVM also....

Downloaded the nvm setup and installed it.... But, NVM is not getting installed in my system.... Because after installing it many times with best of my efforts and precautions. Still, It's not working in my system and I am not getting any response related to it....

When I am checking by running 'nvm -v' command in terminal, that it has installed or not... It's showing an error which means there is no nvm in my system...
(screenshot attached)

[nvm is also not working, after installing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/822v2.png)

Comment: I have solved the issue by Resetting the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by resetting the PC.

I couldn't find any solution to this issue of mine on this Huge world of  Internet. Instead, I was wasting a lot of time in running useless & nonsensical commands in my terminal in the hope that something will work for me. Because, Many websites suggesting various solutions related to similar problems.

But,
I needed to resolve this issue ASAP. So, at the end, I decided to reset my PC's C drive. Of course, It deleted all the softwares from my laptop.

But, I couldn't waste anymore time searching for the solutions or waiting for an angel/expert to come to me & Help me in this phase of intense sadness/trauma.

Therefore, At the end, I asked for the Help from Microsoft, The GOAT, then the Windows/Microsoft came forward to help me & restored the whole C drive of my laptop.

Now, I have gotten rid of all the pain & misery of those software errors. Thanks to Microsoft & Reset PC option of Windows.

If you are also facing such an issue then this can be the last option for you as well. Now, the problem has resolved. Nodejs is working fine.

Therefore, Leaving this solution here! Thanks!